# split hexadecimal string to chunks using brakets

Tags: python, string, split, hex

I have a hex value I want to split it into chunks so I can't store them, I want to split them by using `[]` to specify where the cut is, for example, the hex value is :

0x10d88

I want to split it to `10` , `d8` and `8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question, you can split the string into chunks with a list comprehension, e.g.:

```py
x = "0x10d88"
print([x[i:i + 2] for i in range(2, len(x), 2)])
```

Which returns a list of the chunks:

```
['10', 'd8', '8']
```